# Start/end & left/right for RTL languages in Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, arabic, android-4.2-jelly-bean, right-to-left

I'm trying to make the layout of my app which will include support for RTL languages. The sdk versions targeted will be **15+**. I've used start/end **as well** as left/right in all my layout files, however I noticed the layout doesn't work properly with a RTL language on api level 17 (Android 4.2). Api levels 18 and above seem to handle the double definitions (start & left) just fine though, so I was wondering why the layout messes up on level 17. According to the below text I would expect the same behaviour on level 17 as 18+.

[Native RTL support in Android 4.2:](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

> If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's
> targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should
> use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example,
> android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
>
> If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's
> targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add
> “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For example, you’d
> use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Comment: A workaround could be to create separate layout files for api 17 and above, but surely there must be a more efficient way of handling this?

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem. The layout on API level 17 improves a bit if I remove Left, Right but if I use both left and start, right and end then layout gets messed up on API level 17 however it works fine on 17+. My app supports minSDK 8 so I cannot leave out left and right qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate layout for 17+ like layout-v17 and put default layout in layout. In layout-v17, You need to replace only left->start and right->end on padding, margins, drwableleft etc. dont use left and right on 17 and plus.

There is no other way around.